# Dynamically populating a ComboBox Column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView (DGV) which is populated using a datatable populated by a Stored Procedure.  (All DB calls are correctly returning the requisite data). I then add a combobox column to the DGV which should provide a selection of batchcodes based on the stock code of that row. (Another Stored Procedure Call passing in the StockCode) However, all combo box's on every row are populating with the combined batchcodes for all the rows.  In this example I have tried creating an array of datatables to dynamically assign to the DGV.Row but it's the same result.  I kind of understand why it isn't working but I don't know how to rectify it. (I am assuming that since I am not specifically defining the cell index of the current combobox and assigning it's datasource to a datatable from the array - it is just overwriting it??  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
            // fill the adapter with the executed cmd
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //populate the gridview with the datatable                
            dgv_BOM.DataSource = dt;
            dgv_BOM.AutoSize = true;
            dgv_BOM.AutoResizeColumns();
            dgv_BOM.Columns["StockCode"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            dgv_BOM.Columns["Description"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            dgv_BOM.RowHeadersVisible = false;

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cmb.HeaderText = "Select Batch Code";
            cmb.Name = "cmb";
            cmb.Width = 150;
            dgv_BOM.Columns.Add(cmb);
            DataTable[] dtArray = new DataTable[dgv_BOM.Rows.Count];

            int count = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_BOM.Rows)
            {               
                if (row.IsNewRow) continue;

                stckcd = row.Cells["StockCode"].Value.ToString();
                dtArray[count] = SP_RMBatchCodes(stckcd); //returns a datatable object
                cmb.DataSource = dtArray[cnt];
                cmb.DisplayMember = "BatchNo";

                count++;
            }

            this.dgv_BOM.Columns["Traceable"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: cmb.DataSource = dtArray[cnt]; should be cmb.DataSource = dtArray[count];

Comment: In the last `foreach` loop `cmb` is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`… note the “COLUMN” portion. The `foreach` loop simply changes the `DataSource` for that same combo column. Therefore, the combo box columns items will be the items returned from the last row in the grid. And this is what would be displayed in the grids combo boxes.

Comment: If each row is going to have a different set of values dependent on another cells value… then you will have to manually handle “each” combo box cell’s items for each row. If the combo boxes are all different, then I recommend you create a method that given a “StockCode” would return a collection of “BatchCode”s that you could use for the individual combo boxes. Just a thought.